# What is the correction definition of `sympy.vector.CoordSysCartesian.rotation_matrix`?

Tags: python, sympy, rotational-matrices

A rotation matrix can either be written in two ways.

With **row** unit vectors,

```
[ ex_0 ex_1 ex_2]
[ ey_0 ey_1 ey_2]
[ ez_0 ez_1 ez_2]
```

Or with **column** unit vectors,

```
[ ex_0 ey_0 ez_0]
[ ex_1 ey_1 ez_1]
[ ex_2 ey_2 ez_2]
```

**In the following code which definition is being used? Is DCM in row or column format?**

```
from sympy.vector import CoordSysCartesian
from sympy import symbols, pi, Matrix
theta = symbols('theta')
N = CoordSysCartesian('N')
A = N.orient_new_axis('A', theta, N.k)
dcm = N.rotation_matrix(A).subs({'theta':pi/2})
```

Output,

```
Matrix([
[0, -1, 0],
[1,  0, 0],
[0,  0, 1]])
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Updated to be more clear.

Comment: The inverse of a rotation matrix `R` equals its transposed `R^T`, i.e., `R^{-1}=R^T` and it is also a rotation matrix,. So `R` alwayshas  unit row *and* unit column vectors at the same time. The columns  of the Output matrix show the base vectors of coordinate system `A` in `N`'s coordinates. The row vectors the coordinate system `N` in `A`'s coordinates.